# How do I add shortcode attribute with multiple values in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I add an attribute to Wordpress shortcode function with more than one value? Precisely, I want to add `'order'` attribute with options (values) `asc` or `desc` so I could use it inside the shortcode like `[reviews_category id=1 tag=25 order=asc]` or `order=desc`

What I figured so far is adding

```
    'orderby' => 'taxonomy_cat',
    'order' => desc
```

This does the sorting but it doesn't let me set use the attribute inside shortcode using `asc` or `desc` as sorting direction. It sort only by `desc`

My function is:

```
function review_category_func($atts) {
    $taxID = intval($atts["id"]);
    $ppp = intval($atts["posts_per_page"]);
    $output = '';

    $args = array(
        "post_type" => "reviews",
        "posts_per_page" => $ppp,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'review_category',
                'id' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $taxID
            )
        ),
        'orderby' => 'taxonomy_cat',
        'order' => desc
);
    if (isset($atts['tag'])) {
        $terms = explode(',', $atts['tag']);
        $args['tax_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'review_sources',
                'id' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $terms
            );
    }

    $qry = new WP_Query( $args );

//the rest of the code here....

//ends here

    <?php
    }

    wp_reset_query();

    return $output;
}

add_shortcode("review_category", "review_category_func");
```

Comment: Well then replace the static `desc` with the attribute value from the short code - what exactly is the problem with that? You are already accessing other attributes of the shortcode here, so …?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `shortcode_atts()` as it is explained in codex : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts

```
$args = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'orderby' => 'taxonomy_cat',
        'order' => 'desc',
        ...
    ), 
    $atts
);
```

then you sanitize your variables like :

```
$orderby = esc_attr( $args['orderby'] );
```